# ggplot :Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset which I am trying to plot using `ggplot` and `geofacet`. Below is a sample of my data :

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  date       actuals_vol geo  
  <date>           <dbl> <chr>
1 2014-02-02    9607815. AK   
2 2014-02-09    9552680. AK   
3 2014-02-16    9251645. AK   
4 2014-02-23    9177905  AK   
5 2014-03-02    9254805  AK   
6 2014-03-09    9222940. AK
```

This is the code I am using to plot the data in tile maps:

```
ggplot(cig_prophet_states, aes(date, actuals_vol)) +
  geom_area(fill='#114365') +
  facet_geo(~ geo, grid = "us_state_grid2", label="name") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0("'", substr(x, 3, 4))) +
  labs(title = "GDP by State 1997-2016 ($, trillions)",
       caption = "Data Source: St. Louis FRED",
       x = "Year",
       y = "volume") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```

And I get this following error: `Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied`

Comment: Could you show us the result of `str(my_df$date)` please?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `scale_x_date` instead of `scale_x_continuous`

```
ggplot(cig_prophet_states, aes(date, actuals_vol)) +
  geom_area(fill='#114365') +
  facet_geo(~ geo, grid = "us_state_grid2", label="name") +
  scale_x_date(labels = function(x) paste0("'", substr(x, 3, 4))) +
  labs(title = "GDP by State 1997-2016 ($, trillions)",
       caption = "Data Source: St. Louis FRED",
       x = "Year",
       y = "volume") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```